# Management Studio not show view design

Tags: sql-server, view, ssms

when I try to edit a view, when I select design on it, only a blank window appears.
Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

I am using version 18.11.1 of SQL Server Management Studio, connecting to a SQL Server 16.0.1050

Thank you

I have reinstalled management studio with no results

Comment: SSMS 18 doesn't support SQL Server 2022; update to the latest version (currently 19.1).

Comment: [REF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16#tools): _SSMS version 19.0 is now available and is the recommended version of SSMS for SQL Server 2022 (16.x)_

Comment: Once you get the right version of SSMS installed I would urge you not to use the designer for a view. The designer can generate some truly horrific code. Just write the query however you need to query to be and then add "Create view [MyView] as" at the beginning.

Comment: Just don't use visual designers, they are quirky and limited and imho only serve to add confusion. If you work professionally with SSMS invest in a proper tool such as SQLPrompt that makes working with objects a lot easier, eg hover over query text of view name to easily get view definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!!

Oh thanks for the comments!

I didn't see that upgrading to 18 creates a new installation for 19.
Thanks for the answers. Sorry for not seeing that the latest version was 19!

> Thanks Thom A.
> SSMS 18 doesn't support SQL Server 2022; update to the latest
> version (currently 19.1). –
> Thom A Jun 26 at 9:46

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).